# extracting numbers from strings in perl

Tags: perl

```
$string1 = "2_0_1AU13682.0AV+0.2"

$string2 = "2_0_1AT+0.1CD13681.9"
```

I have these 2 strings. How do I extract the 7 char decimal number from both of them?

From string 1 that would be `13682.0` and from string 2 that would be `13681.9`.

The decimal number is always 7 characters and always in the form of `xxxxx.x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this using *regex* and *match* operator :

```
my $string1 = "2_0_1AU13682.0AV+0.2";
my ($res) = $string1 =~ m/(\d{5}\.\d)/; 
print $res, "\n";
```

See [Extracting-matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) and [Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression, like this:

```
my @data = qw( 2_0_1AU13682.0AV+0.2 2_0_1AT+0.1CD13681.9 );

foreach my $str (@data) {

    if ($str =~ /(\d{5}\.\d)/) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
13682.0
13681.9
```